# Confused about composite functions

Tags: functions

So, I have a question about composite functions.

I have $f(x)=x^2-1$ and $g(x)=(x-1)^2$.
I need to do the composite function $(g\circ f)(x)$.

My question is: do I effectively place the function $f$ inside $g$ like this
$$(g\circ f)(x)=((x^2-1)-1)^2$$
and just simplify that? I think my method is wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're spot on. That's exactly what you do.

Comment: Ok, great, the notes my teacher provided were unclear, thanks for the help!

Comment: With that being said, I just want to make it clear that if they ask you for f(g(x)), it will not equal g(f(x)).  Goodluck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying!